# Hibernate: Error when using sub query

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, subquery

I am trying to write a sub query in this format

```
listObj = session.createQuery("from TablePersistence where column1 not in (select column2 from TablePersistence)").list();
```

Note that I use a different column of the same table in the sub query.

But I get an exception when it is executed. The exception message is:

```
No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.IdentNode 
\-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'column2' {originalText=column2}
```

I can provide the stack trace as well if needed.

But what I feel from looking at the stack trace is that, this is not the way to write a sub query, I am missing something.

Please tell me what is the problem with this query.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give table aliases. Then it will work

```
from TablePersistence table1 where table1.column1 not in (select table2.column2 from TablePersistence table2)
```